# Trying to hide domain from my android application if someone uses url snooper or whireshark

Tags: android, ssl, dns, cloudflare

I have an android application that is connected with my website. This app shows some content from my database in my server that is connected successfully with cloudflare. While i open my application from bluestacks and i snoop it with URL snooper it doesn’t reveal my website url. It only shows ssl urls. That’s the point. I want to hide my domain if someone tries to snoop my application with these programs.

The problem is that i have build the same app in another language in another website with the same things. Admin Panel, database etc. While im trying to snoop my app with URL snooper or Whireshark, it reveals my domain. I don’t want this to happen. I want my domain to be hidden from everyone who tries to snoop my app like i do in my first android app. I have the same options like my other website in my cloudflare. The only difference is that i use wordpress in my first website and in the second one i don't use wordpress. Just a blank page. I don’t have any public content. Everything else is the same.

https://i.gyazo.com/a7f382758685e89edc3831f671c7beb3.png

I found some threads here that they say that domain cannot be hidden while the app takes requests from the server. But i did it in my first application. I was navigating everywhere in my app and my domain was hidden.

*Before i used cloudflare in my first website the domain was shown. After i used cloudflare i figured out that domain was not visible anymore while using url snooper.*

Why i can't do the same in my second website? What you believe can cause that?

Comment: Domain names need to be visible outside of SSL to most Web servers for SNI.

Comment: But how i did it in my first website? While navigating the android application it doesn't reveals the domain. Also a friend of mine did it. If we snoop our apps, the domain is hidden.